# What are the requirements for converting UPI QR codes to upi intents for to be paid via apps?

Tags: paytm, upi

Goal : Scan UPI QR codes through my app and open UPI apps for payment through intent. Basically instead of scanning directly using PayTm, I would like to scan through my app, process some logic and then invoke Paytm or another UPI app.

I have read [NPCI UPI LINKING SPECIFICATIONS 1.6](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15h_Mom1Y7abJJIibUuC2Qjl1gh5LE97U/view) and it seems it's possible, specifically this para at the end.

> Note that there can be 3rd party general purpose utility applications that allows users
> to scan these QR codes, launch the link, allow other innovative transfer protocols
> using sound, etc. Such apps can work as a proxy utility that sends/receives these
> links and then launch the appropriate apps that are listening to these intents.

I have read that I need to sign, but that would be the case in case I was generating UPI links from scratch to my merchant ID or do I need to do even if I'm just passing the UPI link I scanned from merchant QR code?

But when I try do, scan the QR code, which gives me a link `upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR` it does launch the PayTm app but after inserting UPI passcode It says either

> `24 Hr payment limit on your bank has been exceeded`

when doing on my personal UPI ID, scanned from Paytm QR code

> `Payment failed as this mode is not allowed on this UPI ID`

when doing on a shopkeepers QR code.

for example this is the link I got from scanning merchants QR code

```
upi://pay?pa=paytmqrlq0iuwnve5@paytm&pn=Paytm
```

So I had few questions,

- It it actually possible to scan merchant QR codes and transfer the UPI link to another device for UPI payment. Directly or by adding some logic in between?
- do I need to register as a independent developer, I did read on some comments that I need to register on [nfinite.in](https://nfinite.in)

Please provide proper UPI intent documentation and what's possible, specifically expanding on that para from NPCI UPI LINKING SPECIFICATIONS.

Comment: @ParagWadhwani No , I found some answers on stack overflow suggesting that it might work within the same bank network. But I couldn't get it to work for me. It's most probably not allowed anymore due to security issues.